# Why Is Is This Target Selector Argument Not Working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating a command which is supposed to execute a message just once when a certain score is reached.

It worked once, but I made some changes to display a better word separation by adding some whitespace in the text sections within the `tellraw` section. It stopped working from there, even as I undid, switched world etc.
These are the commands I am using at the moment. When I am changing the command to only execute when I am below or above a certain score (`elytraFlight=5000..`, `elytraFlight=..5000`) it works fine, but obviously keeps spamming.

```
/scoreboard objectives add elytraFlight minecraft.custom:minecraft.aviate_one_cm
/execute as @a[scores={elytraFlight=5000}] run tellraw @a [{"text":"[Abgehoben...]: "}, {"selector":"@p[scores={elytraFlight=5000}]"}, {"text":" flog 5 Meter!"}]
```

I don't want to reset the scoreboard - so that I am able to execute another command once a certain second score is reached.

Comment: Additional remark: When that scoreboard is at 5000, you have flown 50 meters, not 5.

Answer (score 1):

The selector `@a[scores={elytraFlight=5000}]` only matches players whose score is exactly 5000. Gliding happens much faster than the very slow speed of 1/100 block per tick, so, the overwhelming majority of the time, the score will jump from <5000 to >5000 without actually hitting 5000. Try `@a[scores={elytraFlight=5000..}]` instead.

Comment: He mentioned this solution in the question, I would suggest `elytraFlight=5000..5100` instead. This way it consistently registers the match, but doesn't spam after the fact.

Comment: The correct solution would be an additional scoreboard objective tracking whether a print has happened, or maybe an advancement. Oh well, at least I explained why `=5000` doesn't work.